# Как проверить метод сортировки списка вставкой на Python?

Tags: python, ооп, тестирование, методы

```
#используем функцию Insertionsort для сортировки списка
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, value, name, next):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.next = next

class InsertionSort:
    def __init__(self, input): #input - ячейка
        self.input = input

    def insertionSort(self):
        sentinel = Cell() #устанавливаем ограничитель для списка вывода
        sentinel.next = None
        self.input = self.input.next #пропускаем ограничитель списка ввода

        while self.input != None: #повторяем до тех пор, пока не вcтавим все элементы в новый список
            next_cell = self.input #берем следующую ячейку для добавления в список
            self.input = self.input.next #заменяем input на input.Next для следующего прохождения цикла
            after_me = sentinel #смотрим, куда добавить следующий элемент в список вывода
            while (after_me.next != None) and (after_me.next.value < next_cell.value):
                after_me = after_me.next
            next_cell.next = after_me.next #вставляем элемент в список вывода
            after_me.next = next_cell
        return sentinel #возвращаем отсортированный список
```

Как (на каких примерах) можно проверить работоспособность метода?

Answer (score 2):

Хотя в коде, кажется, есть ошибки, ответ на поставленный вопрос может быть таким:

Единственный аргумент вашего алгоритма — список `input`. Соответственно для проверки алгоритма нужно создать несколько списков, которые будут достаточно различаться, чтобы покрывать примерно все случаи. Сходу приходят следующие варианты:

1. Пустой список

   ```
   list = None
   listSorted = InsertionSort(list).insertionSort()
   print(listSorted)
   ```
2. Список из одного элемента

   ```
   list = Cell(7, '7', None)
   listSorted = InsertionSort(list).insertionSort()
   print(listSorted)
   ```
3. Список, отсортированный по возрастанию

   ```
   element5 = Cell(5, '5', None)
   element4 = Cell(4, '4', element5)
   element3 = Cell(3, '3', element4)
   element2 = Cell(2, '2', element3)
   element1 = Cell(1, '1', element2)
   list = element1
   listSorted = InsertionSort(list).insertionSort()
   print(listSorted)
   ```
4. Список, отсортированный по убыванию

   ```
   element5 = Cell(1, '1', None)
   element4 = Cell(2, '2', element5)
   element3 = Cell(3, '3', element4)
   element2 = Cell(4, '4', element3)
   element1 = Cell(5, '5', element2)
   list = element1
   listSorted = InsertionSort(list).insertionSort()
   print(listSorted)
   ```
5. Список с одинаковыми элементами

   ```
   element5 = Cell(1, '1', None)
   element4 = Cell(1, '1', element5)
   element3 = Cell(1, '1', element4)
   element2 = Cell(1, '1', element3)
   element1 = Cell(1, '1', element2)
   list = element1
   listSorted = InsertionSort(list).insertionSort()
   print(listSorted)
   ```
6. Список со случайными значениями

   ```
   import random

   lastElement = Cell(0, '0', None)
   list = lastElement
   for i in range(77 - 1):  # 77 — число элементов в списке
       list = Cell(random.randint(0, 10), 'whatever', list)
   listSorted = InsertionSort(list).insertionSort()
   print(listSorted)
   ```